# How do I keep usernames which include "." when I use stringR function?

Tags: r, string, web-scraping, extract, stringr

I want to be able to isolate usernames of instagram users, I have been using the @ symbol as a way to identify users in the pagesource.

My issue is that when a user's name includes a ., my code removes everything from that ., giving me incomplete usernames.

What I need is the full username, i.e. to keep all the username until a blank space occurs.

```
    web_page_read <- read.csv('https://www.instagram.com/p/BY0i2O0FxHl/')
    colnames(web_page_read) <- "id"
    web_page_collect <- web_page_read[web_page_read$id  %like% '@',]
    web_page_collect <- as.data.frame(web_page_collect)
    colnames(web_page_collect) <- "id"
    web_page_collect$id <- str_extract(web_page_collect$id, "(?<=@)\\w+")
    web_page_collect$id  <- sub("^[^@]*@","",web_page_collect$id)
    web_page_collect$id  <- gsub(").*","",web_page_collect$id)
    web_page_collect$id  <- gsub(" .*","",web_page_collect$id)
    web_page_collect$id <- gsub('[â]', '', web_page_collect$id)
    web_page_collect$id <- gsub('[???]', '', web_page_collect$id)
    web_page_collect <- head(web_page_collect,-(nrow(web_page_collect)-1))
```

Comment: Would grabbing everything between the two parenthesis solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the username between the parentheses.

```
library(data.table)
web_page_read <- read.csv('https://www.instagram.com/p/BY0i2O0FxHl/')
colnames(web_page_read) <- "id"
web_page_collect <- web_page_read[web_page_read$id  %like% '@',]
web_page_collect <- as.data.frame(web_page_collect)
colnames(web_page_collect) <- "id"
web_page_collect$id <- gsub("(^.+\\(@)(.+)(\\).+$)","\\2",web_page_collect$id)
```

Use regex to capture groups with the `gsub` function. Loosely translated, your defining the groups as... Group1: start of the string up until `(@`, Group2: All characters, Group3: continue until `)` to the end of the string. Then select the second group.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, you could also search for the text in between "`(@`" and "`)`":

```
insta <- read.csv('https://www.instagram.com/p/BY0i2O0FxHl/')
colnames(insta) <- "id"
collect <- insta[grep("@", insta$id), ]

reg_loc <- gregexpr("(?<=\\(@)(.*)(?=\\))", collect, perl = TRUE)
unlist(regmatches(x = collect, reg_loc))
# [1] "jim.n.tonic" "jim.n.tonic"
```